# Android Picasso How to perform action when placeholder transition into image

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I am using Picasso in my application to load image from a url into an image view. I would like to perform an action, but only once the image has arrived and not when the loading placeholder is visible.

How do I achieve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: ask more clearly, what you want to do and when you want to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use picasso's callback as below

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(url)
    .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                              // do something if its loaded successfully
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                             // do something if its not loaded successfully
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use Picasso [*into* method](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#into-android.widget.ImageView-com.squareup.picasso.Callback-) with [callback](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Callback.html) and execute your code when *onSuccess()* is called.